# how to solve shape error in numpy insert function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was solving NumPy sums from my book.
And wrote the code for it.
Write a python program to insert elements in row as well as in a column of a 2d array at multiple inserting points ()

```
## Q2
import numpy as np
# Write a python program to insert elements in row as well as in a column of a 2d array at multiple inserting points ()
# array of 5,5. with 2,4 row and 1,3 column missing
q2arr2d = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
# [[ 1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10] 
#  [11 12 13 14 15] 
#  [16 17 18 19 20] 
#  [21 22 23 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.delete(q2arr2d,(1,3),axis=0)
q2arr2d = np.delete(q2arr2d,(0,2),axis=1)
print('Given array:\n',q2arr2d)
#  [[ 2  4  5]
#  [12 14 15]
#  [22 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(1,2),([6,8,10],[16,18,20]),axis=0)
print('Array after inserting rows:\n',q2arr2d)
#  [[ 2  4  5]
#  [ 6  8 10]
#  [12 14 15]
#  [16 18 20]
#  [22 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(0,2),([1,5,11,15,21],[3,7,13,17,23]),axis=1)
print('Array after inserting column:\n',q2arr2d)

## Q2
# Write a python program to insert elements in row as well as in a colum of a 2d array at multiple insertin points()
# array of 5,5 .with 2,4 row and 1,3 column missing
q2arr2d = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
# [[ 1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10] 
#  [11 12 13 14 15] 
#  [16 17 18 19 20] 
#  [21 22 23 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.delete(q2arr2d,(1,3),axis=0)
q2arr2d = np.delete(q2arr2d,(0,2),axis=1)
print('Given array:\n',q2arr2d)
#  [[ 2  4  5]
#  [12 14 15]
#  [22 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(1,2),([6,8,10],[16,18,20]),axis=0)
print('Array after inserting rows:\n',q2arr2d)
#  [[ 2  4  5]
#  [ 6  8 10]
#  [12 14 15]
#  [16 18 20]
#  [22 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(0,2),([1,5,11,15,21],[3,7,13,17,23]),axis=1)
print('Array after inserting column:\n',q2arr2d)
```

after executing a error is being shown

```
Given array:
 [[ 2  4  5]
 [12 14 15]
 [22 24 25]]
Array after inserting rows:
 [[ 2  4  5]
 [ 6  8 10]
 [12 14 15]
 [16 18 20]
 [22 24 25]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Codes\NumPy practice\ProjectAndQNA.py", line 61, in <module>
    q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(0,2),([1,5,11,15,21],[3,7,13,17,23]),axis=1)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in insert
  File "C:\Users\VinodKumarPunia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 5377, in insert
    new[tuple(slobj)] = values
    ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,5) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (5,2)
```

if you need any more info related to the code I am ready to answer it
this mismatch erro is not being solved from so much time.
i have tried reshaping but the array in that has different and distorted values.
even changing the axis of insertion doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You have a (5,3) array (right?) and want to add 2 columns.  Then the insert object should be (5,2).  You supply a 2 element tuple, which, as an array is (2,5).  Supply the correct insert shape!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new values need to be consistent with array shape, for example `([1,5,11,15,21],[3,7,13,17,23])` should be  `([[1,3], [5, 7], [11, 13], [15, 17], [21, 23]])`

```
## Q2
import numpy as np
# Write a python program to insert elements in row as well as in a column of a 2d array at multiple inserting points ()
# array of 5,5. with 2,4 row and 1,3 column missing
q2arr2d = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
# [[ 1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10] 
#  [11 12 13 14 15] 
#  [16 17 18 19 20] 
#  [21 22 23 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.delete(q2arr2d,(1,3),axis=0)
q2arr2d = np.delete(q2arr2d,(0,2),axis=1)
print('Given array:\n',q2arr2d)
#  [[ 2  4  5]
#  [12 14 15]
#  [22 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(1,2),([6,8,10],[16,18,20]),axis=0)
print('Array after inserting rows:\n',q2arr2d)
#  [[ 2  4  5]
#  [ 6  8 10]
#  [12 14 15]
#  [16 18 20]
#  [22 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(0,2),([[1,3], [5, 7], [11, 13], [15, 17], [21, 23]]),axis=1)
print('Array after inserting column:\n',q2arr2d)

## Q2
# Write a python program to insert elements in row as well as in a colum of a 2d array at multiple insertin points()
# array of 5,5 .with 2,4 row and 1,3 column missing
q2arr2d = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
# [[ 1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10] 
#  [11 12 13 14 15] 
#  [16 17 18 19 20] 
#  [21 22 23 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.delete(q2arr2d,(1,3),axis=0)
q2arr2d = np.delete(q2arr2d,(0,2),axis=1)
print('Given array:\n',q2arr2d)
#  [[ 2  4  5]
#  [12 14 15]
#  [22 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(1,2),([6,8,10],[16,18,20]),axis=0)
print('Array after inserting rows:\n',q2arr2d)
#  [[ 2  4  5]
#  [ 6  8 10]
#  [12 14 15]
#  [16 18 20]
#  [22 24 25]]
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(0,2),([[1,3], [5, 7], [11, 13], [15, 17], [21, 23]]),axis=1)
print('Array after inserting column:\n',q2arr2d)
```

Comment: Thank you, my code, worked, it was so kind of you to help me.
now the output is the way i wanted it.
[[ 1  2  4  3  5]
 [ 5  6  8  7 10]
 [11 12 14 13 15]
 [15 16 18 17 20]
 [21 22 24 23 25]]

+1 but a small doubt, that when it worked in the first row insertion, then what caused the error to happen in the column insertion?

Comment: when you got an error, you had an array of `shape (5,3)` which means three columns each of them has 5 elements. What you passed was (2, 5) which means 5 columns each of them has 2 elements. For axis 0, you were passing the right shape, for example the first one, you had an array of `(3, 3)` 3 rows each of them has 3 elements, and you passed (2, 3) 2 rows each of them has 3 elements, so they matched.

Answer (score 0):

The code works if you change the index object to one index instead of a tuple.

Replace:
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d,(0,2),([1,5,11,15,21],3,7,13,17,23]),axis=1)

With:
q2arr2d = np.insert(q2arr2d, 2 ,([1,5,11,15,21],[3,7,13,17,23]),axis=1)

Comment: That produces a string list like [2 4 1 3  5] and all , so sorry , but that is wrong